# SSIS Installed, but no SSIS roles appearing when browsing

Tags: sql-server, installation, roles, ssis

Folks, please excuse my lack of knowledge in this area, it's something I've been tasked with fixing, but haven't had much luck with..

I've got a server, with SQL Server 2008 R2 installed, it's the default isntance, and I can see that the SSIS service is installed and currently running.

The issue I have is that, none of the SSIS roles described on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141053.aspx

Are present in the server roles subsection of security... How do I make these available, or perhaps, why are they missing?...

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The roles `db_ssisadmin`, `ds_ssisltduser` and `db_ssisoperator` can be found within the system database **msdb**. Refer screenshot #**1**.

Refer the following link for answer mentioned in `http://social.msdn.microsoft.com`:

[**SSIS Package Roles - Assigning user to Role**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/e80432f4-d2b7-4c8e-b9c8-e591ba99d9fc/)

**Answer excerpt from social.msdn.microsoft.com:**

```
These are just roles in the msdb database.  
To assign the user to the role, you need to have the login as a user in 
that database and assign the role as usual (i.e. go through the gui to 
set the roles of the user or use T-SQL to set them).

USE msdb;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_dtsltduser', N'{User Name Here}';
GO
```

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

Comment: Well, that is equal amounts fantastic and embarassing. Thanks Siva, owe you one!